# Create a shortcut to file in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive

Is it possible to have a shortcut to a file or folder from another folder in Google Drive?
I want to have the same file pointed to from several locations.

Comment: Currently,it is not possible to point same  file to various folder  location in the Google drive.

Comment: @Vembu: That's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

IMPORTANT UPDATE: Google announced that the way that this feature used to work will change. See the details in [Create pointers to any file or folder in Google Drive with shortcuts](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2020/03/shortcuts-for-google-drive.html)

---

## Web UI

### Shortcut feature made generaly available in 2020

1. Right click over the file / folder
2. Select **Add shortcut to Drive**

   [image]

### Adding a file/folder to another locarion

NOTE: As of October 30, 2020 it's still working on my G Suite Business account.

1. Select the file
2. Press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>, the **add** to folder dialog will be shown.
3. Select the folder to add the file.
4. Click the "Add here" button

   [image]

## Google Apps Script

<s>Use Class Folder and [addFile](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#addFile(File)) method</s>

UPDATE: This method is deprecated. See https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/g-suite/simplifying-google-drives-folder-structure-and-sharing-models for details.

Comment: Here https://youtu.be/cz6R55Nlkoc It is not working. Selected web_pages(folder)>I pressed shift 
+ z

Comment: @Aman About what?

Comment: How should I create shortcut? To my web_pages folder(My laptop)

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's not clear to me what are trying to say. Please consider to post a new question to include a brief but complete description of you want to do.

Comment: I have asked a new question . – @Rubén https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/148222/create-a-shortcut-to-a-folder-in-google-drive

Answer (score -1):

This can be done for Windows by:

1. Download the Google Drive app for your PC from [google.com/drive/download/](https://www.google.com/drive/download/)
2. Install the downloaded app, the wizard will ask you for your Gmail address, your password, and a verification code if you have two-step verification enabled on your Google account.
3. On the last screen of the wizard, click the “Sync options” button at the bottom.
4. You can choose which folders in your Google Drive account you want to sync and download to your PC
5. You can then right click any of these files or folders once they are synced to your PC and create a shortcut