# Create a shortcut to a folder in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive

I want to create a shortcut to a folder in My laptop (Synchronized folder).

The folder is in "My laptop"()

[image: Folder location]

I want to create shortcut to web pages in my drive. Earlier there was a shortcut to do this. You just need to right click on your folder.

But in 2020, it does not work.

[image: Shortcut]

[Shift + Z does not work](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c0qgXK5b4sc)

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> works only in "My drive"

[image: No way to create a shortcut]

No option to create a shortcut even in incognito mode.

Comment: "I want to create shortcut to web pages in my drive. Earlier there was a shortcut to do this. You just need to right click on your folder." Does right click isn't working? If so, try using a different web browser and/or try Chrome in incognito mode with all the extensions disabled..

Comment: 'By earlier' I meant a few month ago.

Comment: I tried to create a shortcut in incognito mode But it didn't work.

Comment: this folder is not inside drive. It is a synchronized folder in My laptop. I want to create a shortcut in my drive to it. I have edited my question.

Comment: I think this is a bug. Shift+Z works in My drive. But it does not work in My laptop synchronized folder.